# How to map specific column in entity class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two tables Users and UserRoles. These are the entity class I have created,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public Users {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private Long userId;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CaseCadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn("user_role_id")
private UserRole userRole;

@Column(name = "user_name")
private String userName;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="users_Roles")
public UsersRoles {

@Id
@Column(name = "user_role_id")
private Long userRoleId;

@Column(name = "user_role_name")
private String userRoleName;
}
```

Repository Class,

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users ,Long>{
 public List<Users> findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

For this I am able to get Json result like this.

```
[
 { 
   "userid":"1",
   "username":"user1",
   "userrole": {
    "userroleid":"1",
    "userrolename":"ADMIN",
   }
 },
   { 
   "userid":"2",
   "username":"user2",
   "userrole": {
    "userroleid":"2",
    "userrolename":"INTERN",
   }
}  

]
```

Instead of this can I get something like this..

```
 [
  { 
   "userid":"1",
   "username":"user1",
   "userrolename":"ADMIN",
   },
  { 
   "userid":"2",
   "username":"user2",
   "userrolename":"INTERN",
   }
]
```

What changes I need to do in my entity class for getting only **userrolename** in result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to create a getter for `userrolename`:

```
public String getUserRoleName() {
  return userRole.getUserRoleName();
}
```

To ignore unwanted fields, annotate them with `@JsonIgnore`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the @Converter annotation in your entity. However this way you will have the string (or preferably an enum) in your entity and this will produce your wanted json.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using DTOs  and modelMapper library :

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
    <version>current version</version>
</dependency>

public class UsersDTO {
    String userid ; 
    String username ;
    String userrolename ;
  }
```

UsersDTo dto= modelMapper.map(user, UsersDto.class);

another way  is to instantiate the dto  class in your repo

```
 @Query("SELECT new de.smarterco.example.dto.UsersDTO(u.id, u.username ,ur.name ) 
FROM Users u 
join u.UsersRoles  ur")
    List<UsersDTO> findUsersDTo();
```

And the final way to do this is using jpa projection by creating your dto as interface

```
public intefaceUsersDTO {
    String getuserid() ; 
    String username () ;
    String userRoleName ();
  }
```

and in your repo :

```
@Query("SELECT u.id , u.username ,ur.name as userRoleName  ) 
FROM Users u 
join u.UsersRoles  ur")
    List<UsersDTO> findUsersDTo();
```